# why i get {error :2061 identifier {ctor

Tags: c++

In header file:

```
#ifndef  Array_h
#define  Array_h

#include "stdafx.h"

using namespace std;

template<class T>
class Arrayc
{ 
private:
    int Arraysize;
    int length;
    T *array;
public:
    Arrayc(int size);
    ~Arrayc();
};
template<class T>
Arrayc<T>::Arrayc(int size)
{
    Arraysize = size;
    length = 0;
    array = new T[Arraysize];
}
#endif
```

In main source file:

```
Arrayc<int> *Arrayofintegers;
Arrayc<float> *Arrayoffloat;
// These lines have the error
Arrayofintegers = new Arrayc<int>::Arrayc(10);
Arrayoffloat = new Arrayc<float>::Arrayc(5);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need specify the scoped name, `Arrayc<T>::Arrayc`, when *defining* the constructor.

To call the constructor, simply use `Arrayc<T>(/*args*/)`.

Of course, you really don't even need `new` at all, but that's unrelated to the error.

Answer (score -1):

You are not passing any clues to your constructors of what you want T to be at the time that you use them. I'd suggest adding a parameter T to your constructor, even if you only use it as a phony initializer value, so that the compiler can deduce what type Arrayc() will be, e.g., `new Arrayc(10, 0)` or `new Arrayc (10, 0.0f)`

Comment: Constructor itself is not a template. I suggest fixing it to `new Arrayc<int>(10)` and `new Arrayc<float>(5)` optionally a template factory.